# How to move a cube using an animation

Tags: c#, animation, unity-game-engine, gameobject

I'm trying to make a cube in unity move using an animation I made in unity. When I press "W" the cube should animate to another position, but when the animation is finished it goes back to where the animation started. Also when I do the animation the animation starts at the position where the animation was created. I tried fixing this with applying root animation to my cube and checking the "Generating root motion curves at runtime" option in my animation inspector. But when I do that the cube won't move. Can I get some help with this issue.

Answer (score 0):

This behavior is quite normal, once the animation stops. You have a couple of options.

- If the animation is only about translation and rotation, then do it the straightforward way (without the animation) and by manipulating position and rotation
- Create another animation that starts in the last frame of your moving animation and loop it (you have finite state machines in Unity for animations)
- Cache the current position and rotation of your object, detect the
  end of the animation and set the position and rotation to the last
  cached values.